# Compiling Scipy with Anaconda's free MKL libraries

Tags: python, scipy, fortran, anaconda, intel-mkl

I am trying to install Scipy from its master branch on Github into an Anaconda environment in Windows 7. This requires compiling Scipy from source. [Scipy can use MKL as its BLAS/LAPACK library](https://www.scipy.org/scipylib/building/windows.html#intel-math-kernel-library-mkl) and [Anaconda comes with free MKL now](https://docs.continuum.io/mkl-optimizations/). I get an error saying that `no lapack/blas resources found`. How do I tell Scipy setup to use the Anaconda MKL?

Fresh install instructions within Anaconda:

```
conda create --name scipy_master python=3.6 numpy cython
activate scipy_master
pip install https://github.com/scipy/scipy/tarball/master
```

Here is the relevent text from the error:

```
lapack_mkl_info:
    C:\Anaconda3\envs\scipy_master\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py
        :655: UserWarning: Specified path C:/Anaconda3/envs/scipy_master\Library\lib is 
        invalid.
    return self.get_paths(self.section, key)
    C:\Anaconda3\envs\scipy_master\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py
        :664: UserWarning: Specified path C:/Anaconda3/envs/scipy_master\Library\include is 
        invalid.
    return self.get_paths(self.section, key)
    libraries mkl_core_dll,mkl_intel_lp64_dll,mkl_intel_thread_dll not found in []
    NOT AVAILABLE

...

File "scipy\linalg\setup.py", line 20, in configuration
    raise NotFoundError('no lapack/blas resources found')
numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources found
```